# Function that imports data

Tags: r

Im trying to create a function that imports my data into R. Whenever I call this function though it runs through it but I don't see my data set anywhere

```
inputData <- function(){
  teams <- read.csv('C:/Users/BT_1N3_24/Desktop/PremierLeaguePlayers.csv', header = TRUE)
  currentTeam <- read.csv('C:/Users/BT_1N3_24/Desktop/TeamStats.csv', header = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: In R, broadly speaking, a function creates its own environment and variables inside the function are restricted to that environment. You should take those lines outside of the function to have the objects `teams` and `currentTeam` appear in the global environment.

Comment: So I'm not able to make them global variables through a function or something like that?

Comment: You can by using `<<-` rather than `<-` but that's very bad form and un-R-like. It's much easier if you return a list of data.frames that you want to load.

Comment: As far as this function goes, you can do `currentTeam <- inputData()` and create a `currentTeam` object in the global environment. Functions return the last line by default unless specified otherwise. If you need these lines inside a function for some reason, then you can make a list that holds the data objects and return the list. Why do you need it inside a function though?

Comment: you can make it a global variable if you use operator  `<<-` instead of  `<-`. Try assigning it this way  `teams  <<- read.csv(.....)`

Comment: So you're saying there is really no point in creating this function and to just load my data sets before hand?

Answer (score 2):

All functions are locally scoped in R. If you want to pass something out of the environment, it must be returned as an object. I would write your code like this:

```
inputData <- function(){
  teams <- read.csv('C:/Users/BT_1N3_24/Desktop/PremierLeaguePlayers.csv', header = TRUE)
  currentTeam <- read.csv('C:/Users/BT_1N3_24/Desktop/TeamStats.csv', header = TRUE)
  list(teams, currentTeam)
}

## call the function
data.list <- inputData()
```